# Nested binding with templates

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am creating 'Lessons' tab in my application. The problem is in displaying data.

Timetable(`List<DayInfo>`) is binded to ItemsControl. Each `DayInfo` is an item in this ItemsControl. I tried to bind `Exams` collection to nested ItemsControl placed in ItemTemplate, but It's not working.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. I guess my `Exams` binding is the problem.

Timetable:

```
private List<DayInfo> timetable;
public List<DayInfo> Timetable
{
    get { return timetable; }
    set
    {
        timetable = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Timetable);
    }
}
```

There is DayInfo.cs:

```
public class DayInfo : IValue
{
    public string DayName { get; }
    public List<ExamEntry> Exams { get; }
    ...
}
```

ExamEntry.cs:

```
public class ExamEntry : DayEntry, IValue
{
     public string Description { get; }
     ...
}
```

XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl
               ItemsSource="{Binding Timetable}">
                   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                              <StackPanel
                                  Orientation="Horizontal" />
                          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                   <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                       <GroupStyle>
                           <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                               ...
                           </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                           <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Margin="0">
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           </GroupStyle.Panel>
                       </GroupStyle>
                   </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                               <Label
                                   Content="{Binding DayName}" /> <!-- It still works -->
                               <ItemsControl
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Exams}">
                                   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                       <DataTemplate>
                                           <Label
                                               Content="{Binding Description}" /> <!-- It's not displayed -->
                                       </DataTemplate>
                                   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                               </ItemsControl>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Is the innermost ItemsControl displaying a correct number of empty items, or no items at all?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with this piece of code. I've forgotten about another part of project, where Timetable was bugged. Sorry for confusion.